# How to combine two decimals into one big-endian?

Tags: node.js, endianness, bigint

I've got two integers like `1511461841`, `253093752` which represents seconds + nanoseconds since unix epoch.

How can I combine them into a big-endian [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)?

`1511461841253093752` is too large to store as a Number which makes this tricky and simply concatting two [UInt32BE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writeuint32be_value_offset_noassert) buffers isn't correct either.

(To be clear, I want to encode the number `1511461841253093752`, *not* two separate integers)

Log base 2 of 1511461841253093752 is 60.4, so the result should be 8 bytes.

---

I can get the first (right-most) byte simply by doing 253093752 % 256 but I can't figure out how to get the second byte without using a bigint library. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this piece of code, using the [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer)
module, performs what you requested. I've added some comments to explain
what is happening.

```
// Load a module to represent big integers in javascript
var bigInt = require("big-integer");

// The value that we want to represent as big endian
var num = bigInt("1511461841253093752", 10);

// First we're going to store the bytes of this value in
// little endian order
var values = [];
while (num.compare(bigInt.zero) != 0) {
    values.push(num.mod("256").valueOf());
    num = num.divide("256");
}

// Fill with zeros if needed. 
var desiredLength = 8;
while (values.length < desiredLength) {
    values.push(0);
}

// Reverse the order to get big endian order and create
// a buffer from the array
values = values.reverse();
var buf = Buffer.from(values);

// This outputs <Buffer 14 f9 ca 89 5b 72 d1 78>
console.log(buf);
```

Comment: To be clear, since I presently have this big number as two separate numbers, I should just take the nanoseconds, convert it to a string, and left-pad with 0s up to 9 digits, then concat them? I think that'll generate the bigint as a string properly.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in both Node.js and browser JS using the [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) library as [brm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828217/brm) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47462109/65387).

#### Node

```
function uuid() {
    const [sec,ns] = getTime(); 

    let num = BigInt(sec + padNano(ns));

    let {quotient,remainder} = num.divmod(4294967296);

    let buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(16);
    buf.writeUInt32BE(quotient.valueOf(),0,true);
    buf.writeUInt32BE(remainder.valueOf(),4,true);
    Crypto.randomBytes(8).copy(buf, 8);

    return buf;
}


function padNano(ns) {
    let padLen = 9 - ns.length;
    if(padLen > 0) {
        return '000000000'.slice(0,padLen) + ns;
    }
    return String(ns);
}
```

#### Browser

```
export default function uuid() {
    const [sec,ns] = getTime();

    let num = BigInt(sec + String(ns).padStart(9,'0'));

    let {quotient,remainder} = num.divmod(4294967296);

    let buf = new ArrayBuffer(16);
    let dataView = new DataView(buf,0,8);
    dataView.setUint32(0, quotient.valueOf(), false);
    dataView.setUint32(4, remainder.valueOf(), false);

    let cryptView = new Uint8Array(buf, 8, 8);
    crypto.getRandomValues(cryptView);

    return buf;
}
```

#### Details

As I mentioned in the question, the numbers represent seconds and nanoseconds. 1e9 nanoseconds = 1 second, so the right number is capped at 999999999, which takes at most 30 bits to represent.

I didn't put a limit on the "seconds" in my question, but we can cap it at 32 bits to make the math simpler. Unix epoch + 2<sup>64</sup> nanoseconds = July 21, 2554 which is far enough in the future for my purposes.

Thus *both* numbers fit neatly in a uint32. So all we have to do is split the big in two by dividing it by 2<sup>32</sup>. The left half will be the quotient, and the right half will be the remainder. We could do this in two operations, but the big-integer has a handy function for this already called `divmod` so I used that.

Next we just have to write the two parts into a buffer using big-endian. Fortunately both browser and Node have functions for this, so we can do it with just two writes.